# Which option best suits the MVP model

Tags: android-mvp

While I was refactoring some code I had a doubt.

If some error happens in the model class, would it be better to call a method of the model class from the presenter class to check if something went wrong, or instead call a method of the presenter class from the model class when the error happens?

For example: Call a method of a `model` class (from `presenter` class)

```
if (modelClass.isWhateverRight()) 
    //Do something
```

Or Call a method of the `presenter` class (from `model` class)

```
if (something)      
    presenterClass.showMessage();
```